# Why am I getting Invalid argument error on my connect calls?

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to modify the wrk codebase so that it will connect to multiple servers instead of just the one. I have found and am modifying the `connect_socket` function to this end but am getting the following output when it runs:

```
143.204.186.52
connect: Invalid argument
64.190.62.111
connect: Invalid argument
45.33.18.44
connect: Invalid argument
64.190.62.111
connect: Invalid argument
52.128.23.153
connect: Invalid argument
173.255.194.134
connect: Invalid argument
^C  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     0.00us    0.00us   0.00us    -nan%
    Req/Sec     0.00      0.00     0.00      -nan%
  0 requests in 1.66s, 0.00B read
  Socket errors: connect 100000, read 0, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:      0.00
Transfer/sec:       0.00B
```

Here is the modified function that I am calling:

```
static int connect_socket(thread *thread, connection *c) {
    struct addrinfo *addr = thread->addr;
    struct aeEventLoop *loop = thread->loop;
    int fd, flags;
    char ip[128];
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
    
    if (fscanf(fp, "%128s", ip) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", ip);
    }
    
    memset(&myaddr, '0', sizeof(myaddr));
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(80);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &myaddr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
    }

    fd = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);

    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) == -1) {
        if (errno != EINPROGRESS) goto error;
    }

    flags = 1;
    setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &flags, sizeof(flags));

    flags = AE_READABLE | AE_WRITABLE;
    if (aeCreateFileEvent(loop, fd, flags, socket_connected, c) == AE_OK) {
        c->parser.data = c;
        c->fd = fd;
        return fd;
    }

  error:
    perror("connect");
    thread->errors.connect++;
    close(fd);
    return -1;
}
```

I guess it must be a problem with my arguments to `connect`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you could transform this into a runnable example (something we can cut and paste and run without dependencies). If you drop the threading and the nonblocking io and just iterate over addresses, attempting to connecto to port 80, does it work?

Comment: Your `addr->ai_socktype` is `0`. Likely, `socket` returns `-1`.

Comment: @user58697 No. It's set to ```SOCK_STREAM```

Comment: What is `addr`?

Comment: I suggest you use `strace()` so you can see the actual arguments that are being passed.

Comment: Typo: `'0'` should be `'\0'` in the call to `memset()`.

Comment: Or just `0` with no quotes.

Comment: I've fixed the problem. Instead of ```addr->ai_family``` I needed ```AF_INET```.

Answer (score 1):

This code is a logic mess.

The use of the `addrinfo` struct implies the `getaddrinfo()` function is being used elsewhere before the thread is started.

Your thread is being passed in an `addrinfo`, and is then creating the socket based on the IP address type specified by that `addrinfo`, but is ignoring the actual IP address stored in the `addrinfo` (which could be either an IPv4 or IPv6 address). It is instead obtaining an IP address as a string from elsewhere, parsing it only as an IPv4 address, and then passing it to `connect()` in a `sockaddr_in` struct. `connect()` can fail with an "invalid argument" error in that case if the socket is not an IPv4 (`AF_INET`) socket, ie if it is an IPv6 (`AF_INET6`) socket instead, which requires a `sockaddr_in6` struct.

To fix this, you need to either:

- get rid of the `sockaddr_in` and use the IP address in the `sockaddr` as-is:

  `connect(fd, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen)`
- get rid of the `sockaddr` and hard-code the socket type as `AF_INET` to match the use of `sockaddr_in`:

  `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the following line:

```
fd = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
```

It should be:

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
```